# Trying to click on a banner using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on the banner Administration

```
<div class="wah-global-ask-banner-item-container5 wah-clickable wah-provider-launch" data-provider="admin-link" id="admin-banner">
 <div class="wah-global-ask-banner-item">
 <div class="wah-global-ask-banner-item-icon-container-small" style="">
 <div class="wah-global-ask-banner-item-icon iconMonitor128" style="zoom: 50%;"></div></div>
 <div class="wah-global-ask-banner-item-title wah-global-ask-banner-item-title-paa" style="top: 52px; left: 0px; font-size: 24px;">Administration</div>
```

I already tried using `find_element_by_class_name()` and it didn't work.

How can I do it?

Comment: What didn't work? Was element not found? Are you just looking for a locator that works? The html snippet is a bit unclear on what's nested in which div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CssSelector:

`FindElement(By.CssSelector(".wah-global-ask-banner-item-title.wah-global-ask-banner-item-title-paa"));`

There is a nice extension for Chrome which helps you determine the best CSS Selectors to locate elements called [CSS Selector Helper for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-selector-helper-for-c/gddgceinofapfodcekopkjjelkbjodin?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Administration** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.wah-global-ask-banner-item div.wah-global-ask-banner-item-title.wah-global-ask-banner-item-title-paa"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='wah-global-ask-banner-item-title wah-global-ask-banner-item-title-paa' and text()='Administration']"))).Click();
  ```